# I want to call someone but this keeps appearing. Im so confused. I only have one apple id that i used to everything

Tags: ipad, icloud, facetime, call

[image]I included a screenshot. I hope someone can help. Im no techie sorry.

Comment: Are you trying to make calls from your iPad? Or is this appearing on an iPhone? Have you followed the instructions, i.e. signed in with the same Apple-ID?

Comment: From my ipad. I only use one apple id so i am sure that it is signed in with the same id. There are no other instructions besides the one in the photo. Ive been struggling with this problem since i got ipad.

Comment: If the iPad was not obtained as new or remanufactured unit directly from Apple or an Apple Store, the iPad may be signed in to another AppleID from a previous owner. If you did get it from Apple, return it as it is defective. If you obtained it from someone else, contact the previous owner to get the iPad signed out of the previous owner's AppleID, so you can sign in on yours. If you can't contact the previous owner...you're out of luck with this particular iPad.

Comment: Have you checked your FaceTime settings in settings to ensure your Apple ID is signed in for FaceTime?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica if i would reset the ipad, since everything is downloaded in my icloud, would the previous owners apple id be signed out automatically from the ipad? thank you so much sir, i never knew about thing

Comment: @JBallin yes, the facetime is signed in with my apple id.

Comment: No. Resetting the iPad will not solve the problem. if the iPad is signed in with a previous user's AppleID, it will remain signed in with the previous user's AppleID until the previous user (or someone who knows the previous user's AppleID and AppleID password) signs it out from the previous user's Apple ID account.

Comment: When you open settings, do you see your name at the top? This would confirm that you’re signed into your Apple ID on the phone.

Comment: @JBallin, yes, i see my name at the top. my apple id is signed in.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica thank you so much sir, i will try to contact the previous owner.